# jQuery - splitting items by highlighting X amount of items one color, then the next amount another, etc (example included)

Tags: jquery, listitem, css-selectors

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8xBeW/1/

In the fiddle example you can see the idea I'm *kind of* going for.  Only instead of highlighting every 4 items, I'd like the list to calculate it as if I was splitting it into 4 equal parts.  Now obviously it's not always going to be divisible by whatever number I put in, and that's fine.  But here's a quick example of what I'd like:

Item1
Item2
Item3
Item4
Item5
Item6
Item7
Item8

I'd like to take that list and put in a "4" and have the following output...

Item1 [highlighted 1st color]
Item2 [highlighted 1st color]
Item3 [highlighted 2nd color]
Item4 [highlighted 2nd color]
Item5 [highlighted 3rd color]
Item6 [highlighted 3rd color]
Item7 [highlighted 4th color]
Item8 [highlighted 4th color]

And if it was an odd list, for instance, if I wanted it split in 5, it would be 8/5 which is 1.6 so it would round up to 2, and highlight every 2 anyway right?  Not really sure how to handle THAT... but that's why I'm here.

Any ideas?  This is just a personal project I'm trying to do to separate a list of tasks and delegate them out to X amount of team members easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
    var total = $("#list-for-testing li").length;
    var num = total / $el.val( );
    var current = 1;

    $('#list-for-testing li').each( function( i ) {
        if( i > ( current * num ) )
            current++;
        $(this).attr('class', 'selected' + current);
    } );
```

I used multiple classes to make it work (`selected1`, `selected2`, etc) but that should be enough to make it work from there.

Comment: Just because I'm annoying, instead of declaring i, you could use the `i` that's passed to the each function as the first parameter like `.each(function(i) {...`

Comment: @Nicosunshine Yup. I threw that together and didn't think about the fact that it's passed in. Updated my answer.